# Odoo pos receipt customization

Tags: odoo-12

How to modify the Point of sale print receipt to get GST included in it.
i seen the posTicket in pos.xml but cant get the details in the print receipt

```
<tr>
  <td><t t-esc="taxdetail.name" /></td>
  <td>GST:</td>
  <td class="pos-right-align">                      
      <t t-esc="widget.format_currency(taxdetail.amount)" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To make changes you need to extend template of PosTicket. But in your case if you want tax 'GST' then you just configure that tax and that will automatically comes up.

Comment: @KevalMehta can you tell me how to configure the SMS services in odoo

Answer (score 0):

There are certain free apps which helps you fulfil your SMS integration feature. You can download it from odoo app store and used it.

Comment: where should we had to place that downloaded app module -- is that to be in addons? are somewhere i cant get to know

Comment: I suggest you create another dict in file explorer and put all the custom addons there. Add path of that dict of custom addons in your config file after base addons.